# Where to save a picture in iOS and then to show it in app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a project for Android and iOS that needs to show a user image and video in a view.

In Android this was simple. I could just get the path using

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures);
```

And then I used System.IO to check file existence and finally, show that in the view (shared project).

What should be the equivalent in iOS?

When I plug the target iPhone in a USB port and browse its files, I only see one folder called DCIM which contains some folders with pictures.

Can I use that folder? how can I access it from the iOS project?

I tried with:

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonPictures);
```

But it returns an empty string.

Any help, please?

Thanks

Jaime

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows

Comment: Thanks... By reading one of those documents, I have created a folder in the solution and placed the files there, configuring the build action as content. That way, I can access the files from the app.